# Operator precedence (bitwise '&' lower than '==')

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, operator-precedence

In the C programing language, why do the bitwise operators (& and |) have lower precedence than the equality operator (==)? It does not make sense to me.

Comment: Because that's the way they designed it. Also, parentheses are cheap.

Comment: Why it doesn't make sense to you?

Comment: I got caught out when using the expression if (a & b == c), took me a while to find out why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You need to ask Brian Kernighan or Dennis Ritchie.
From this forum: http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/167377-operator-precedence

> The && and || operators were added later
>       for their "short-circuiting" behavior. Dennis Ritchie admits in
>       retrospect that the precedence of the bitwise operators should have
>       been changed when the logical operators were added. But with several
>       hundred kilobytes of C source code in existence at that point and an
>       installed base of three computers, Dennis thought it would be too big
>       of a change in the C language...

So, that might be a reason?  I'm guessing since there are several layers of bitwise precendence (unlike relational comparisons) that it's cruft that's existed since...forever...and just was never corrected.

Comment: That quote is actually misquoted. Dennis Ritchie explains this himself in his paper "Chistory", which [you can read here](http://cm.bell-labs.co/who/dmr/chist.html). In my opinion, Ritchie's wording is much better. Ritchie regretted having the precedence as such, but it was made so to have minimal conversion friction from the B language, C's predecessor, when he was first forming the C language. B only supported `&` on cells and didn't have an explicit boolean operator due to B's lack of a type system. This also explains why "true" means "not 0" -- bitwise AND doesn't always yield a perfect 1.

Comment: But `==` isn't a short-circuiting operator so why does this answer the question?  However, thank you @Qix, because your comment also explains why the bitwise operators all have different (seemingly arbitrary) precedences - they're from B as seen in the _[B Tutorial Appendix D](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/btut.html)_ (a question which had been vexing me).  (And my guess is that B did it that way for no other reason than that it is easy to write a recursive descent parser with that kind of expression grammar.)

Answer (score 18):

It doesn't make sense to Dennis Ritchie, either, in retrospect.

http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/dmr-on-or.html

&& and || were added to the language after | and &, and precedence was maintained for reasons of compatibility.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have an authoritative answer as to why K&R chose the precedence they did.  One example that makes a fair amount of sense would be this one:

```
if (x == 1 & y == 0) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Since this is the bitwise AND operator it uses a non-short-circuiting evaluation mode, as would

```
if (x == 1 | y == 0) {
    /* ... */
}
```

use the non-short-circuiting OR operator.  This is probably why they chose to have the precedence group this way, but I agree with you that in retrospect it doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  Why would you use the bitwise operator instead of a logical one in this case?

Comment: @Nathan Fellman- Caladain's answer seems to hit this one on the head.

Comment: Right.  The precedence of `&` and `|` makes perfect sense as logical operators, but little sense as bitwise operators.

Comment: Kudos for this awesome non-short-circuiting logical operators usage. Never thought of that.

Comment: @NathanFellman If you really need both `aaaa()` and `bbbb()` to run and you like unreadable code, you'd write `if (aaaa() == 1 & bbbb() == 0)`. There really is no other reason.