# C++ symbol scope search order different for template and non-template class?

Tags: c++, templates, scope

```
#include <iostream>

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "global foo()" << std::endl;
}

struct A {
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "A::foo()" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B : public A {
    void call()
    {
        foo();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv )
{
    B b;
    b.call();
    return 0;
}
```

This gives [expected result](http://ideone.com/WHjpk):

```
A::foo()
```

However after changing two lines (class B to template):

```
#include <iostream>

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "global foo()" << std::endl;
}

struct A {
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "A::foo()" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T> // change here
struct B : public T {
    void call()
    {
        foo();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv )
{
    B<A> b; // and here
    b.call();
    return 0;
}
```

I get [unexpected result](http://ideone.com/2p4hR):

```
global foo()
```

And using `this->` is not an option as I am trying to create a "fallback" mechanism.

Comment: Would `call() { T::foo(); }` be ok to use? It works.

Comment: How about calling `T::foo();` from `B::call`?

Comment: It works fine VS 11 Beta. Calls A::foo(). Not sure if beta compiler can be taken into consideration.

Comment: In VS11 Beta, calling ::foo() invokes the global function and foo() calls A::foo().

Comment: @chris Last line in my question states clearly it would not work: http://ideone.com/YuoIH

Comment: Which compiler are you using ?

Comment: @elmo: Putting `using T::foo;` in `B` would work, as long as `foo` exists in all the classes you use to instantiate `A`. Perhaps that's an option.

Comment: You should have mentioned that the global `foo` should be called if `T` doesn't implement `foo`(based on your ideone example).

Comment: @Jagannath: Any compliant compiler should behave as described. Microsoft's compiler performs name lookup at the wrong point (template instantiation, rather than template definition), as discussed in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273176).

Comment: @MikeSeymour yes, saw the other SO question in the link. I did not know about this concept till now.

Comment: @elmo: this might intersting to read http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Name-lookup.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you get is an expected result. This is called "Two-phase name lookup" in the C++ standard.

Names inside templates are divided into two types:

**Dependent** – names that depend on the template parameters but aren’t declared within the template.

**Non-dependent** – names that don’t depend on the template parameters, plus the name of the template itself and names declared within it.

When the compiler tries to resolve some name in the code, it first decides whether the name is dependent or not, and the resolution process stems from this distinction. While non-dependent names are resolved "normally" – when the template is defined, the resolution for dependent names happens at the point of the template’s instantiation.

`foo();` in `B::call` in your example is a non-dependent name, so it is resolved to global `foo()` at the point of template definition.

Comment: How does that work with Jagannath's comment "It works fine VS 11 Beta. Calls A::foo()."?
I know MS is not the best thing to validate any standards against. Also any references to C++ (03) standard would be nice. And do you know how to make it behave as I want?

Comment: @elmo: Microsoft C++ does not implement two-phase name lookup correctly. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273176).

Comment: @elmo: To make it work your way :
template <typename T>
struct B : public T {
    void call()
    {
        T::foo();//Add T:: to the code
    }
};

Comment: @elmo: The relevant section of the standard is C++11 14.6.2/3: "In the definition of a class or class template, if a base class depends on a _template-parameter_, the base class
scope is not examined during unqualified name lookup either at the point of definition of the class template
or member or during an instantiation of the class template or member." (C++03 14.6.2/3 says more-or-less the same thing, if you're interested in historicaly standards for some reason).

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer explains why you see that behaviour, but not how to acheive the "fallback" behaviour you want. That can be done using [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error), by introducing a pair of member template overloads, one of which will only exist if the base class has a member function called `foo`.

```
template <typename T>
struct B : T {
    template <void (T::*)()> struct has_mem_fn {};

    template <typename U> void call(has_mem_fn<&U::foo>*) {this->foo();}
    template <typename U> void call(...) {foo();}

    void call() {call<T>(0);}
};

struct X {};

int main()
{
    B<A> ba;
    ba.call();  // A::foo()

    B<X> bx;
    bx.call();  // global foo()
}
```

UPDATE: I've just noticed your comments in another answer, where you say you're aware of this method, but can't use it due to having to support dysfunctional compilers. In that case, I'm afraid that what you want is probably impossible.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You need to specifically tell to use T class method.</s>

```
template <typename T>
struct B : public T {
    void call()
    {
        T::foo();
    }
};
```

---

But as for a fallback mechanism, you can check this question: [Is it possible to write a template to check for a function's existence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence)

Using a **Substitution failure is not an error** (SFINAE), you can check for a method `foo` in T, and then run the proper method.

Comment: Please see his comment and the last line of his question.

Comment: Again: last line in my question states clearly it would not work: http://ideone.com/YuoIH

Comment: @elmo: why do you except it works when ``C`` structure has no ``foo`` method? http://ideone.com/WcLQE

Comment: @Jagannath: i meant "what method/function the compiler should link in the string 33 (``c.call()``)"? ``struct C`` has no ``foo``, ``B`` has no ``foo``, what should be called in this case?

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Didn't see that.

Comment: Edited to, what i think, is a better answer for your case.

Comment: As for edited version I am well aware of that approach. Unfortunately I have to create code that is compiled with CC version Sun C++ 5.9 SunOS_sparc Patch 124863-12 2009/04/21 and any SFINAE tricks I could come up with make that compiler fail miserably. If I had proper compilers I wouldn't probably reach that question.