# Method of a template class uses a typedef from the global scope. Compiler bug?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

I have a code in VC2010 which I've reduced to a small example.

`Test.h:`

```
#pragma once

template <typename TPixel>
struct Image
  {
  typedef TPixel PixelType;
  };

template <typename TImageType>
struct Operation
  {
  void DoOperation()
    {
    ImageType::PixelType value = 0;   
// I've done a misprint here. It should be TImageType::PixelType
    }
  };
```

`Test.cpp:`

```
void Test()
  {
  typedef Image<char> ImageType;

  Operation<ImageType> op;
  op.DoOperation();
  }
```

As I expected, that produces an error.

`test.h(14): error C2653: 'ImageType' : is not a class or namespace name`

Now, let's change `test.cpp` just a little bit.

```
typedef Image<char> ImageType;

void Test()
  {
  Operation<ImageType> op;
  op.DoOperation();
  }
```

Now it compiles! Surprisingly enough, `ImageType` in `DoOperation()` now matches with the global typedef in `test.cpp`.

My question: why does it compile? Is that a Visual C++ bug or a standard behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it that `test.cpp` includes `test.h` *before* the typedef, so it's actually

```
#include "test.h"
typedef Image<char> ImageType;

void Test()
  {
  Operation<ImageType> op;
  op.DoOperation();
  }
```

Completed like this, it is indeed a bug, or standard nonconforming behavior with regard to two phase lookup. Names that do not depend on a template parameter should be resolved relative to the point of declaration of the template.

[I guess this is known behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273176/what-exactly-is-broken-with-microsoft-visual-cs-two-phase-template-instanti).

Comment: After looking at the link you provide, I agree with you.