# Why is this template inference failing

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-argument-deduction

This code won't compile with clang++ 6.0  or g++4.9.1 (Code has no meaning but this is the minimum example that makes it happen):

```
#include <forward_list>

template<typename T>
T getItem(typename std::forward_list<T>::const_iterator it) {
    return *it;
}

template<typename T>
void foo() {
    std::forward_list<T> list;
    auto item = getItem(list.cbegin());
}

template<typename T>
void bar(const std::forward_list<T>& list) {
    auto item = getItem(list.cbegin());
}

int main() {
    std::forward_list<int> list;
    bar(list);
}
```

I get this error

```
t2.cpp:17:17: error: no matching function for call to 'getItem'
    auto item = getItem(list.cbegin());
                ^~~~~~~
t2.cpp:22:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'bar<int>' requested here
    bar(list);
    ^
t2.cpp:4:3: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
T getItem(typename std::forward_list<T>::const_iterator it) {
  ^
1 error generated.
```

To fix it I need to change `bar()`'s call like this:

```
template<typename T>
void bar(const std::forward_list<T>& list) {
    auto item = getItem<T>(list.cbegin());
}
```

I don't understand why the compiler is not able to infer the template argument, and the strange thing is that the compiler is perfectly happy with `foo()`.

Comment: You can "deduce" parameter yourself: `template<typename T>
auto getItem(T it) -> decltype(*it) {
    return *it;
}`.
Not very good idea, but it works ))

Comment: What's wrong with `auto item = *list.begin();`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're trying to deduce a template argument from a non-deduced context, *§ [temp.deduct.type]/5*

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> — The nested-name-specifier of a type that was specified using a qualified-id.

i.e.

```
template<typename T>
T getItem(typename std::forward_list<T>::const_iterator it)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and *§ [temp.deduct.type]/4*

> In certain contexts, however, the value does not participate in type deduction, but instead uses the values of template arguments that were either deduced elsewhere or explicitly specified. **If a template parameter is used only in non-deduced contexts and is not explicitly specified, template argument deduction fails.**

If you try to instantiate `foo` [it will give the same error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d276969039a25387). You're not getting errors for `foo` with the code above since dependent names are only looked up at instantiation (this is commonly referred to as *two-phase lookup*). Cfr. [Semantic correctness of non-instantiated C++ template functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25405958/1938163)