# unordered linked list in C++

Tags: c++

I am learning linked list recently,  below is the code, the linkedlist.h file:

```
    #ifndef H_LinkedListType
    #define H_LinkedListType  

    #include <iostream>
    #include <cassert>

    using namespace std; 

    //Definition of the node

    template <class Type>
    struct nodeType
    {
        Type info;
        nodeType<Type> *link;
    };

    template <class Type>
    class linkedListIterator
    {
    public:
       linkedListIterator();
         //Default constructor
         //Postcondition: current = NULL;

       linkedListIterator(nodeType<Type> *ptr);
         //Constructor with a parameter.
         //Postcondition: current = ptr;

       Type operator*();
         //Function to overload the dereferencing operator *.
         //Postcondition: Returns the info contained in the node.

       linkedListIterator<Type> operator++();    
         //Overload the pre-increment operator.
         //Postcondition: The iterator is advanced to the next 
         //               node.

       bool operator==(const linkedListIterator<Type>& right) const; 
         //Overload the equality operator.
         //Postcondition: Returns true if this iterator is equal to 
         //               the iterator specified by right, 
         //               otherwise it returns the value false.

       bool operator!=(const linkedListIterator<Type>& right) const; 
         //Overload the not equal to operator.
         //Postcondition: Returns true if this iterator is not  
         //               equal to the iterator specified by  
         //               right; otherwise it returns the value 
         //               false.

    private:
       nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to point to the current 
                                //node in the linked list
    };

    template <class Type>
    linkedListIterator<Type>::linkedListIterator()
    {
        current = NULL;
    }

    template <class Type>
    linkedListIterator<Type>::
                      linkedListIterator(nodeType<Type> *ptr)
    {
        current = ptr;
    }

    template <class Type>
    Type linkedListIterator<Type>::operator*()
    {
        return current->info;
    }

    template <class Type>
    linkedListIterator<Type> linkedListIterator<Type>::operator++()   
    {
        current = current->link;

        return *this;
    }

    template <class Type>
    bool linkedListIterator<Type>::operator==
                   (const linkedListIterator<Type>& right) const
    {
        return (current == right.current);
    }

    template <class Type>
    bool linkedListIterator<Type>::operator!=
                     (const linkedListIterator<Type>& right) const
    {    return (current != right.current);
    }


    //*****************  class linkedListType   ****************

    template <class Type>
    class linkedListType
    {
    public:
        const linkedListType<Type>& operator=
                             (const linkedListType<Type>&);  
          //Overload the assignment operator.

        void initializeList(); 
          //Initialize the list to an empty state.
          //Postcondition: first = NULL, last = NULL, count = 0;

        bool isEmptyList() const;
          //Function to determine whether the list is empty. 
          //Postcondition: Returns true if the list is empty,
          //               otherwise it returns false.

        void print() const;
          //Function to output the data contained in each node.
          //Postcondition: none

        int length() const;
          //Function to return the number of nodes in the list.
          //Postcondition: The value of count is returned.

        void destroyList();
          //Function to delete all the nodes from the list.
          //Postcondition: first = NULL, last = NULL, count = 0;

        Type front() const; 
          //Function to return the first element of the list.
          //Precondition: The list must exist and must not be 
          //              empty.
          //Postcondition: If the list is empty, the program
          //               terminates; otherwise, the first 
          //               element of the list is returned.

        Type back() const; 
          //Function to return the last element of the list.
          //Precondition: The list must exist and must not be 
          //              empty.
          //Postcondition: If the list is empty, the program
          //               terminates; otherwise, the last  
          //               element of the list is returned.

        virtual bool search(const Type& searchItem) const = 0;
          //Function to determine whether searchItem is in the list.
          //Postcondition: Returns true if searchItem is in the 
          //               list, otherwise the value false is 
          //               returned.

        virtual void insertFirst(const Type& newItem) = 0;
          //Function to insert newItem at the beginning of the list.
          //Postcondition: first points to the new list, newItem is
          //               inserted at the beginning of the list,
          //               last points to the last node in the list, 
          //               and count is incremented by 1.

        virtual void insertLast(const Type& newItem) = 0;
          //Function to insert newItem at the end of the list.
          //Postcondition: first points to the new list, newItem 
          //               is inserted at the end of the list,
          //               last points to the last node in the list,
          //               and count is incremented by 1.

        virtual void deleteNode(const Type& deleteItem) = 0;
          //Function to delete deleteItem from the list.
          //Postcondition: If found, the node containing 
          //               deleteItem is deleted from the list.
          //               first points to the first node, last
          //               points to the last node of the updated 
          //               list, and count is decremented by 1.

        linkedListIterator<Type> begin();
          //Function to return an iterator at the begining of the 
          //linked list.
          //Postcondition: Returns an iterator such that current is
          //               set to first.

        linkedListIterator<Type> end();
          //Function to return an iterator one element past the 
          //last element of the linked list. 
          //Postcondition: Returns an iterator such that current is
          //               set to NULL.

        linkedListType(); 
          //default constructor
          //Initializes the list to an empty state.
          //Postcondition: first = NULL, last = NULL, count = 0; 

        linkedListType(const linkedListType<Type>& otherList); 
          //copy constructor

        ~linkedListType();   
          //destructor
          //Deletes all the nodes from the list.
          //Postcondition: The list object is destroyed. 

    protected:
        int count;   //variable to store the number of 
                     //elements in the list
        nodeType<Type> *first; //pointer to the first node of the list
        nodeType<Type> *last;  //pointer to the last node of the list

    private: 
        void copyList(const linkedListType<Type>& otherList); 
          //Function to make a copy of otherList.
          //Postcondition: A copy of otherList is created and
          //               assigned to this list.
    };


    template <class Type>
    bool linkedListType<Type>::isEmptyList() const
    {
        return(first == NULL);
    }

    template <class Type>
    linkedListType<Type>::linkedListType() //default constructor
    {
        first = NULL;
        last = NULL;
        count = 0;
    }

    template <class Type>
    void linkedListType<Type>::destroyList()
    {
        nodeType<Type> *temp;   //pointer to deallocate the memory
                                //occupied by the node
        while (first != NULL)   //while there are nodes in the list
        {
            temp = first;        //set temp to the current node
            first = first->link; //advance first to the next node
            delete temp;   //deallocate the memory occupied by temp
        }
        last = NULL; //initialize last to NULL; first has already
                     //been set to NULL by the while loop
        count = 0;
    }

    template <class Type>
    void linkedListType<Type>::initializeList()
    {
        destroyList(); //if the list has any nodes, delete them
    }

    template <class Type>
    void linkedListType<Type>::print() const
    {
        nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to traverse the list

        current = first;    //set current so that it points to 
                            //the first node
        while (current != NULL) //while more data to print
        {
            cout << current->info << " ";
            current = current->link;
        }
    }//end print

    template <class Type>
    int linkedListType<Type>::length() const
    {
        return count;
    }  //end length

    template <class Type>
    Type linkedListType<Type>::front() const
    {   
        assert(first != NULL);

        return first->info; //return the info of the first node 
    }//end front

    template <class Type>
    Type linkedListType<Type>::back() const
    {   
        assert(last != NULL);

        return last->info; //return the info of the last node   
    }//end back

    template <class Type>
    linkedListIterator<Type> linkedListType<Type>::begin()
    {
        linkedListIterator<Type> temp(first);

        return temp;
    }

    template <class Type>
    linkedListIterator<Type> linkedListType<Type>::end()
    {
        linkedListIterator<Type> temp(NULL);

        return temp;
    }

    template <class Type>
    void linkedListType<Type>::copyList
                       (const linkedListType<Type>& otherList) 
    {
        nodeType<Type> *newNode; //pointer to create a node
        nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to traverse the list

        if (first != NULL) //if the list is nonempty, make it empty
           destroyList();

        if (otherList.first == NULL) //otherList is empty
        {
            first = NULL;
            last = NULL;
            count = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            current = otherList.first; //current points to the 
                                       //list to be copied
            count = otherList.count;

                //copy the first node
            first = new nodeType<Type>;  //create the node

            first->info = current->info; //copy the info
            first->link = NULL;        //set the link field of 
                                       //the node to NULL
            last = first;              //make last point to the
                                       //first node
            current = current->link;     //make current point to
                                         //the next node

               //copy the remaining list
            while (current != NULL)
            {
                newNode = new nodeType<Type>;  //create a node
                newNode->info = current->info; //copy the info
                newNode->link = NULL;       //set the link of 
                                            //newNode to NULL
                last->link = newNode;  //attach newNode after last
                last = newNode;        //make last point to
                                       //the actual last node
                current = current->link;   //make current point 
                                           //to the next node
            }//end while
        }//end else
    }//end copyList

    template <class Type>
    linkedListType<Type>::~linkedListType() //destructor
    {
       destroyList();
    }//end destructor

    template <class Type>
    linkedListType<Type>::linkedListType
                          (const linkedListType<Type>& otherList)
    {
        first = NULL;
        copyList(otherList);
    }//end copy constructor

             //overload the assignment operator
    template <class Type>
    const linkedListType<Type>& linkedListType<Type>::operator=
                          (const linkedListType<Type>& otherList)
    { 
        if (this != &otherList) //avoid self-copy
        {
            copyList(otherList);
        }//end else

         return *this; 
    }

    #endif
```

the unorderedLinkedList.h file:

```
    #ifndef H_UnorderedLinkedList
    #define H_UnorderedLinkedList  

    #include "linkedList.h"

    using namespace std;

    template <class Type> 
    class unorderedLinkedList: public linkedListType<Type>
    {
    public:
        bool search(const Type& searchItem) const;
          //Function to determine whether searchItem is in the list.
          //Postcondition: Returns true if searchItem is in the 
          //               list, otherwise the value false is 
          //               returned.

        void insertFirst(const Type& newItem);
          //Function to insert newItem at the beginning of the list.
          //Postcondition: first points to the new list, newItem is
          //               inserted at the beginning of the list,
          //               last points to the last node in the  
          //               list, and count is incremented by 1.

        void insertLast(const Type& newItem);
          //Function to insert newItem at the end of the list.
          //Postcondition: first points to the new list, newItem 
          //               is inserted at the end of the list,
          //               last points to the last node in the 
          //               list, and count is incremented by 1.

        void deleteNode(const Type& deleteItem);
          //Function to delete deleteItem from the list.
          //Postcondition: If found, the node containing 
          //               deleteItem is deleted from the list.
          //               first points to the first node, last
          //               points to the last node of the updated 
          //               list, and count is decremented by 1.
    };


    template <class Type>
    bool unorderedLinkedList<Type>::
                       search(const Type& searchItem) const
    {
        nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to traverse the list
        bool found = false;

        current = first; //set current to point to the first 
                         //node in the list

        while (current != NULL && !found)    //search the list
            if (current->info == searchItem) //searchItem is found
                found = true;
            else
                current = current->link; //make current point to
                                         //the next node
        return found; 
    }//end search

    template <class Type>
    void unorderedLinkedList<Type>::insertFirst(const Type& newItem)
    {
        nodeType<Type> *newNode; //pointer to create the new node

        newNode = new nodeType<Type>; //create the new node

        newNode->info = newItem;    //store the new item in the node
        newNode->link = first;      //insert newNode before first
        first = newNode;            //make first point to the
                                    //actual first node
        count++;                    //increment count

        if (last == NULL)   //if the list was empty, newNode is also 
                            //the last node in the list
            last = newNode;
    }//end insertFirst

    template <class Type>
    void unorderedLinkedList<Type>::insertLast(const Type& newItem)
    {
        nodeType<Type> *newNode; //pointer to create the new node

        newNode = new nodeType<Type>; //create the new node

        newNode->info = newItem;  //store the new item in the node
        newNode->link = NULL;     //set the link field of newNode
                                  //to NULL

        if (first == NULL)  //if the list is empty, newNode is 
                            //both the first and last node
        {
            first = newNode;
            last = newNode;
            count++;        //increment count
        }
        else    //the list is not empty, insert newNode after last
        {
            last->link = newNode; //insert newNode after last
            last = newNode; //make last point to the actual 
                            //last node in the list
            count++;        //increment count
        }
    }//end insertLast


    template <class Type>
    void unorderedLinkedList<Type>::deleteNode(const Type& deleteItem)
    {
        nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to traverse the list
        nodeType<Type> *trailCurrent; //pointer just before current
        bool found;

        if (first == NULL)    //Case 1; the list is empty. 
            cout << "Cannot delete from an empty list."
                 << endl;
        else
        {
            if (first->info == deleteItem) //Case 2 
            {
                current = first;
                first = first->link;
                count--;
                if (first == NULL)    //the list has only one node
                    last = NULL;
                delete current;
            }
            else //search the list for the node with the given info
            {
                found = false;
                trailCurrent = first;  //set trailCurrent to point
                                       //to the first node
                current = first->link; //set current to point to 
                                       //the second node

                while (current != NULL && !found)
                {
                    if (current->info != deleteItem) 
                    {
                        trailCurrent = current;
                        current = current-> link;
                    }
                    else
                        found = true;
                }//end while

                if (found) //Case 3; if found, delete the node
                {
                    trailCurrent->link = current->link;
                    count--;

                    if (last == current)   //node to be deleted 
                                           //was the last node
                        last = trailCurrent; //update the value 
                                             //of last
                    delete current;  //delete the node from the list
                }
                else
                    cout << "The item to be deleted is not in "
                         << "the list." << endl;
            }//end else
        }//end else
    }//end deleteNode


    #endif
```

the main.cpp test file below

```
    //This program tests various operation of a linked list
    //34 62 21 90 66 53 88 24 10 -999 

    #include <iostream>
    #include "unorderedLinkedList.h"

    using namespace std; 

    int main()
    {
        unorderedLinkedList<int> list1, list2;          //Line 1
        int num;                                        //Line 2

        cout << "Line 3: Enter integers ending " 
         << "with -999" << endl;                    //Line 3
        cin >> num;                                     //Line 4

        while (num != -999)                             //Line 5
        {
            list1.insertLast(num);                      //Line 6
            cin >> num;                                 //Line 7
        }

       cout << endl;                                   //Line 8

       cout << "Line 9: list1: ";                      //Line 9
       list1.print();                                  //Line 10
       cout << endl;                                   //Line 11
       cout << "Line 12: Length of list1: " 
            << list1.length() << endl;                 //Line 12

       list2 = list1;      //test the assignment operator Line 13

     `enter code here`  cout << "Line 16: list2: ";                     //Line 14
       list2.print();                                  //Line 15
       cout << endl;                                   //Line 16
       cout << "Line 17: Length of list2: " 
            << list2.length() << endl;                 //Line 17

       cout << "Line 18: Enter the number to be "
         << "deleted: ";                            //Line 18
       cin >> num;                                     //Line 19
       cout << endl;                                   //Line 20

       list2.deleteNode(num);                          //Line 21

       cout << "Line 22: After deleting " << num 
            << " list2: " << endl;                     //Line 22
       list2.print();                                  //Line 23
       cout << endl;                                   //Line 24

       cout << "Line 25: Length of list2: " 
            << list2.length() << endl;                 //Line 25

       cout << endl << "Line 26: Output list1 " 
            << "using an iterator" << endl;            //LIne 26

       linkedListIterator<int> it;                     //Line 27

       for (it = list1.begin(); it != list1.end();  it++)
         cout << *it << " ";                         //Line 29
       cout << endl;                                   //Line 30

       return 0;                    
   }
```

but when i compile the above C++ code for unordered linked list  ,  unfortunately, i come across the error message below:

```
File                    Line    Column  Description
unorderedLinkedList.h   null    null    In member function 'bool unorderedLinkedList<Type>::search(const Type&) const':
unorderedLinkedList.h   49  15  'first' was not declared in this scope
unorderedLinkedList.h   null    null    In member function 'void unorderedLinkedList<Type>::insertFirst(const Type&)':
unorderedLinkedList.h   69  21  'first' was not declared in this scope
unorderedLinkedList.h   72  5   'count' was not declared in this scope
unorderedLinkedList.h   74  9   'last' was not declared in this scope
unorderedLinkedList.h   null    null    In member function 'void unorderedLinkedList<Type>::insertLast(const Type&)':
unorderedLinkedList.h   90  9   'first' was not declared in this scope
unorderedLinkedList.h   94  9   'last' was not declared in this scope
unorderedLinkedList.h   95  9   'count' was not declared in this scope
unorderedLinkedList.h   99  9   'last' was not declared in this scope
unorderedLinkedList.h   102 9   'count' was not declared in this scope
unorderedLinkedList.h   null    null    In member function 'void unorderedLinkedList<Type>::deleteNode(const Type&)':
unorderedLinkedList.h   114 9   'first' was not declared in this scope
unorderedLinkedList.h   123 13  'count' was not declared in this scope
unorderedLinkedList.h   125 17  'last' was not declared in this scope
unorderedLinkedList.h   150 17  'count' was not declared in this scope
unorderedLinkedList.h   152 21  'last' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: This is basically same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128796/why-can-i-call-base-template-class-method-from-derived-class

Comment: anyone who can help me out ? very appreciated

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but linkedListType should have a virtual destructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimized example:

```
template <class T>
struct Base {
    int foo;
};

template <class T>
struct Derived : Base<T> {
    void bar() { foo = 0; }
};
```

This doesn't compile because `foo` is a nondependent name so it's looked up at template definition time, and this lookup doesn't consider the base class template because `Base` can be explicitly specialized later so there's no guarantee that it actually has a member called `foo`.

To fix this, use `this->foo` or `Base<T>::foo` to make it a dependent name, or add a `using` declaration in `Derived` to bring `foo` in scope - `using Base<T>::foo;`.