# Is accessing member variables in case of multiple Inheritance compiler dependent? How to do it correctly?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, multiple-instances

I have for following Situation:

```
template <class K> class A
{
public:
    int a;
};

class B
{
public:
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
};


template <class K> class C : public A<K>, public B
{
public:
    virtual void DoSomething()
    {
        a = 3;      // ***
    }
};
```

Now this works on MSVC, however gcc tells me for the line with the 3 stars : "error: 'a' was not declared in this scope". I figured out that I can replace the line with

```
A::a = 3;
```

and it works on gcc (well mingw) as well. Do we have to add the original class name all the time to be standard conform? I thought, I only have to add it if names collide otherwise.

I'm using mingw32 (gcc) 4.8.1.

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/qFePZt). Which version of GCC are you using?

Comment: No, it should work always. And it is too basic to be a compiler bug. Are you sure this is the __exact__ code you compiled?

Comment: Historically, MSVC has had issues with standard compliance, so I am not overly surprised by what you have found.

Comment: works on gcc version 4.6.3

Comment: Hmm ok, sorry. I oversimplified. This actually works for me as well. I edited it.

Comment: Isn't this the [infamous MSVC lack of two-phase lookup](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6273176/420683) again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it makes sense...

GCC is right, and MSVC is wrong. It should not work because `a` is *template dependent* but the expression `a;` is not.

That is, the meaning you intend of `a` depends on a template argument (in your case `K`), but the expression that contains it does not. And since the compiler cannot be sure that the instantiation of `A<K>` will have a member named `a`, it simple assumes it does not.

There are several easy solutions, all of them involve using a template dependent expression so resolve `a`:

```
this->a = 3; //my favourite
A<K>::a = 3; //you found this one
```

**EXAMPLE**:

Let's see an example of why it should not work:

```
template <typename K> struct A
{
    int a;
};

int a; //global variable to make things more interesting

template <typename K> struct B : A<K>
{
    void foo()
    {
        a = 3; //does it refer to A<K>::a or ::a?
    }
};

//template specialization of A<int>
template <> struct A<int>
{
};

B<float> bf; // what does bf.foo() do?
B<int> bi; //and bi.foo()?
```

Also, you can make the opposite situation:

```
template <typename K> struct A
{
};

int a; //global variable to make things more interesting

template <typename K> struct B : A<K>
{
    void foo()
    {
        a = 3; //does it refer to A<K>::a or ::a?
    }
};

//template specialization of A<int>
template <> struct A<int>
{
    int a; //now the member variable is in the specialization
};

B<float> bf; // what does bf.foo() do?
B<int> bi; //and bi.foo()?
```

As you can see, the standard C++ behavior is there for you protection, so that the code you write in a template will always refer -more or less- to the same things:

- `a`: will be always the non template (global in the example) variable, if available. If not, it is a compiler error.
- `this->a`: will be always the member variable, if available. If not, a compiler error.

Comment: Hmm. Cool that you recognize the issue. :) Could you elaborate on the explanation why the Compiler cannot be sure that an instaniation of A<K> will have a member named a? Looking at the definition of template A, all instantiations will have a member a. No?

Comment: @marc40000: Sure! Added. You are forgetting template specializations, those can be arbitrarily different from the unspecialized one.

Comment: Thanks for editing :) Is it really for my protection? The same situation in the non-template case allows me to just use a instead of A::a. Why is it different here?

Comment: @marc40000: because in the non-template case what `a` means is known when the compiler parses the function code. But in the template case, the compiler doesn't know what the members inherited from `A<K>` will be: there may be an `a` or there may not. The fact that the definition of the `template class A` is available means nothing because of the possibility of template specializations. The actual members of `A<K>` will not be known until the instantiation of the templates, but then only template dependent expression will be re-interpreted. See the examples: what behavior would you prefer?

Comment: So, is it possible to have an A<K0> that has a member named a and an A<K1> that does not have a member named a at the same time by using template specialization?

Comment: @marc40000: Exactly! Look up SFINAE for really cool uses of this feature.