# Overloading lookup during template instanciation

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, clang, icc

I have a piece of code that compiles using icc or visual c++ but does not when I use gcc or clang.

The problem comes from the fact that gcc/clang want `bindTo(std::string& s, const int& i)` to be defined before `A<T>::bind(T& t)` or `callBindTo(T& t)` definition and not just before code instantiation.

My question is: Why Visual and icc does not require it ? and which compiler have the right behavior with respect to the standard ?

```
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class A
{
  public:
  static void bind(T& t);
};

template <typename T>
void A<T>::bind(T& t)
{
  std::string s;
  bindTo(s, t);
}

template <typename T>
void callBindTo(T& t)
{
  std::string s;
  bindTo(s, t);
}

void bindTo(std::string& s, const int& i)
{
  s = i;
}

int main()
{
  int i;
  A<int>::bind(i);
  callBindTo(i);
}
```

Comment: This is called forward declaration. A function declaration / prototype should always precede its usage. Typically all function are declared in the header files which are included in the source file.

Comment: The term to search for is *two-phase lookup*.

Comment: Thanks for the missing pointer ;)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273176/what-exactly-is-broken-with-microsoft-visual-cs-two-phase-template-instanti

Answer (score 2):

GCC and Clang have the correct implementation. As the comments hint, the name `t` is looked up during instantiation, in the second name lookup phase, when `T==int`. This doesn't introduce any additional namespaces for Argument-Dependent Lookup. The compiler therefore has to look for all declarations of `bind`, in the global namespace, up to the point where it's actually used.

The last part is important. The **scope** for lookups is determined by the location of the template definition, not by the location of the first instantiation. This is a good thing. What if there were 5 instantiations, with 5 increasingly big overload sets? You'd have to instantiate the template each time, redoing overload resolution, and potentially getting 5 different results.

If you don't think that's bad enough, how would you deal with this in name mangling? You'd have `callBindTo<int>` and `callBindTo<int>`, two instantiations that could only be distinguished by the overload set of `bind` at their point of instantiation.

No, the current rules are sane. Yes, the Argument Dependent Lookup can add extra namespaces, and that's tricky, but all instantiations of `callBindTo<std::string>` add the same namespace `std`. And with that example, we see it's a good thing you called your function `bindTo` and not `bind` - you almost dragged in `std::bind`.

Comment: You still have the "different overload set" problem with current rules, though it does significantly mitigate it. [temp.point]/8 and [temp.dep.candidate]/1 make doing this kind of thing ill-formed NDR (or UB, which is essentially equivalent).