# template overload resolution trouble

Tags: c++, templates, c++03, overload-resolution, c++98

Given this code:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
std::string stringify(const T&) {
    return "{?}";
}

template <typename T>
std::string proxy(const T& in) {
    return stringify(in);
}

// trying to specialize "stringify()"

template <typename T>
std::string stringify(const std::vector<T>& in) {
    return "vector specialization!";
}

template <>
std::string stringify(const std::vector<int>& in) {
    return "INT vector specialization!";
}

int main() {
    std::cout << proxy(1); // calls the 1st

    std::vector<int> intVec;
    std::cout << proxy(intVec); // calls the 1st

    std::vector<double> dblVec;
    std::cout << proxy(dblVec); // calls the 1st

    return 0;
}
```

How can I specialize `stringify()` for `vector<>` after `proxy<>`?

Currently I get `{?}{?}{?}`

If I delete this one - `stringify(const std::vector<T>& in)` then the `vector<int>` starts getting called because it would be a specialization of the first.

Then I would get `{?}INT vector specialization!{?}`

Is there any way to call any of the 2 vector specialization stringification functions from `proxy()` - if they are defined last - after the `proxy()` function?

Is there a way to partially specialize on `vector<>` and still get called from `proxy<>`?

I don't want to specialize for `vector<int>`, `vector<double>`, `vector<UserType>`...

**EDIT:** forgot to mention I need this for `C++98`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, avoid specializing function templates, prefer overloading. See [Herb Sutter's article](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) on the potential pitfalls.

Secondly, the issue you're running into involves how name lookup works for dependent names in function templates. Inside `proxy<T>`, `stringify` is a dependent name - it depends on `T`. That name will be looked up at the point of definition of the template (which will find `stringify<T>(const T&)` and not the other overload) and again at the point of instantiation in the associated namespace of the arguments (which would be `std`). Neither of those lookups find your other functions.

It's that second part of lookup - the argument-dependent lookup - that we can take advantage of. Let's just stick everything in one namespace (which I'm naming `N` arbitrarily, feel free to rename as appropriate):

```
namespace N {
    struct helper { };

    template <typename T>
    std::string stringify(helper, const T&) {
        return "{?}";
    }
}

template <typename T>
std::string proxy(const T& in) {
    return stringify(N::helper(), in);
}
```

Ok, so far we've changed absolutely nothing. We still get `{?}` in all cases. But the now we can stick further **overloads** (not specializations) of `stringify` still in that namespace but after the definition of `proxy`:

```
namespace N {    
    template <typename T>
    std::string stringify(helper, const std::vector<T>& ) {
        return "vector overload!";
    }

    std::string stringify(helper, const std::vector<int>& ) {
        return "INT vector overload!";
    }
}
```

Those two overloads will be found by the second phase of the name lookup because `N` is an associated namespace of `helper`. Now `proxy(intVFec)` will find all three overloads of `stringify` instead of just the one. And now your code prints:

```
{?}INT vector overload!vector overload!
```

as desired. None of the above requires C++11.

Comment: thanks a lot! you saved my ass! I love it when c++ magic works and I don't get it - still trying to NOT learn about ADL :) life is short.

Comment: @onqtam ADL is pretty important - after all it's how `std::cout << "Hello, World!"` works!

Comment: just found out that this doesn't compile under VC++6... maybe ADL is broken (only when using templates for overloads! free function overloads are fine) - it says in ```proxy()``` that the call is ambiguous if there are more than 1 specializations. Maybe its time to drop support for it

Comment: @onqtam It's not ADL that's broken, it's [VC++ that is](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6273176/2069064)

Comment: I hit that two-phase lookup problem a few days ago with the same stringification through the proxy function - and because of it I started making template specializations instead of just free function overloads - but now I can go back to free functions - yey!