# Explicit this pointer needed to access member of base class during c++ partial template specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, language-lawyer

While this is not actually a problem, it confuses the hell out of me.

In the following code, I cannot access a member of my base class in my derived class, without using the `this` pointer.
Can someone point me to the rule that forces me to use the `this` pointer here?

I tested it with gcc 8.2 and intel 18.0.2, as I first assumed it must be some compiler bug. But both compilers complain, so I guess its something I'm missing here?
You can just copy/paste this code to http://www.onlinegdb.com to test it out.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename U>
class MyClassBase {
public:
    MyClassBase() 
            : somebool(true) {
    };
    virtual ~MyClassBase() {};
    virtual void someMethod()=0;
protected:
    bool somebool;
};

template<typename T, typename U>
class MyClass : public MyClassBase<T, U> {
public:
    MyClass() : MyClassBase<T, U>() {};
    void someMethod() override;
};


template <typename T>
class MyClass<T, std::string> : public MyClassBase<T, std::string> {
public:
    MyClass() : MyClassBase<T, std::string>() {};
    void someMethod() override;
};

//implementation generic class
template <typename T, typename U>
void MyClass<T, U>::someMethod() {
    std::cout << "Generic: " << this->somebool << std::endl; //works
    std::cout << "Generic: " << somebool << std::endl; //fails to compile
}

//implementation specialization
template <typename T>
void MyClass<T, std::string>::someMethod() {
    std::cout << "Specialized: " << this->somebool << std::endl; //works
    std::cout << "Specialized: " << somebool << std::endl; //fails to compile
}

int main()
{
    MyClass<int, int> class_generic;
    MyClass<int, std::string> class_specialized;
    class_generic.someMethod();
    class_specialized.someMethod();
    return 0;
}
```

The error I get is that the base class member is unknown.

```
main.cpp: In member function ‘void MyClass<T, U>::someMethod()’:
main.cpp:41:33: error: ‘somebool’ was not declared in this scope
     std::cout << "Generic: " << somebool << std::endl;
                                 ^
main.cpp: In member function ‘void MyClass<T, std::basic_string<char> >::someMethod()’:
main.cpp:47:37: error: ‘somebool’ was not declared in this scope
     std::cout << "Specialized: " << somebool << std::endl;
                                     ^
```

Comment: You could also access it from the derived class as `MyClassBase<T,U>::somebool`.

Comment: You have to because of the template aspect. Probably lots of duplicates on this.

Comment: Thanks, and yeah I guessed this has to do with the templates and that there are duplicates, but I wouldn't know what to search for specifically. Is there like a rule of the C++ standard that dictates when to use `this`, and why? Because I've never encountered this with other templated classes and methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I use alias from a base class in a derived class with templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334150/why-cant-i-use-alias-from-a-base-class-in-a-derived-class-with-templates) (same story but with a type instead of a member).

Comment: @Tasche [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24368629/3309790) might help you.