# Type definitions dependent on template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, using

I am currently working with template classes in C++. In these classes, I am using types that are again dependent on the template parameters. In order to not type the parameters all the time, I did something along the lines of

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
    using someName = someClass<T>;
}
```

There are some more examples in the actual code but this should illustrate the idea.

This worked fine, as long as I only needed `someName` in class `A`. But my project has since grown and I have added other templated classes that should use `someName` as well.

**My question is:** What is the best way to define (several) types as above that depend on some template parameters and use them in multiple other classes (at best without having the write out all of the parameters constantly)?

My ideas so far:

1. Of course, I can simply copy `using someName = std::someClass<T>;` to all the classes using it. But this is not very elegant and both adding classes and adding such types becomes increasingly cumbersome.
2. An alternative would be to write all the `using`s into a file and let the compiler do the copy & pasting for me via `include`. But I am not sure whether this would actually work and it seems to be a very brute force approach and in general not good practice.
3. I also tried different approaches involving `using` but none of them worked so far. Still, it seems to me that this might be the most promising route to the solution.

Maybe I am making things way too complicated and there is an easier and more straightforward solution to this.

Comment: Looks like there's no way, even inherit not work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334150/why-cant-i-use-alias-from-a-base-class-in-a-derived-class-with-templates

Comment: ??? vector ??? Your example did not have vector. Unclear what your use case is. Is it to have one parameter, maybe vector, used as predefined alias in many other templated things?

Comment: A type_traits class might group those typedef, but `std::vector<T>` is probably shorter/simpler that `typename myTrait<T>::vector`...

Comment: You can create template aliases, like `someContainerClass<T>` which could become `vector` or `list` depending on `T`. Not sure if that helps though. You question is a bit unclear.

Comment: @Klaus Sorry, I changed the example to be more generic but forgot to adjust the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a struct which defines each common alias:

```
template<typename T> struct Aliases {
    using value_type = T;
    using reference = T&;
};
```

...and inherit from it:

```
template<typename T> class Foo: public Aliases<T> {};
template<typename T> class Bar: public Aliases<T> {};
template<typename T> class Baz: public Aliases<T> {};
```

Some tests:

```
static_assert(std::same_as<Foo<char>::value_type, char>);
static_assert(std::same_as<Bar<int>::reference, int&>);
static_assert(std::same_as<Baz<int>::reference, int&>);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this. Although this is probably not what inheritance was originally intended for ^^