# How to pick overload based on return type

Tags: c++

In my project enum values often need writing out to log files or to be persisted as strings. So, I've been providing functions ToString and StringToEnum as in the following examples:

```
namespace Mine
{
    enum class Color { red, green, blue };

    inline std::wstring ToString(Color c)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
        case Color::red: return L"red";
        case Color::green: return L"green";
        case Color::blue: return L"blue";
        default: THROW_MACRO("Unexpected value[{}] for enum[{}]", c, L"Color");
        }
    }

    inline void StringToEnum(const std::wstring& inEnumValueName, Color& out)
    {
        if (inEnumValueName == L"red")
        {
            out = Color::red;
        }
        else if (inEnumValueName == L"green")
        {
            out = Color::green;
        }
        else if (inEnumValueName == L"blue")
        {
            out = Color::blue;
        }
        else
        {
            THROW_MACRO("Unexpected value[{}] for enum[{}]", inEnumValueName, L"Color");
        }
    }
}
```

When I use StringToEnum I end up writing:

```
Color c;
StrintToEnum(L"red", c);
// use c
```

I would really like to be able to declare and initialize on one line and write:

```
auto c = ToEnum<Mine::Color>(L"red);
```

I defined ToEnum like this and put it in a header to be included:

```
namespace CommonCode
{
    template<class T>
    T ToEnum(const std::wstring& enumValueName)
    {
        T value;
        StringToEnum(enumValueName, value);
        return value;
    }
}
```

The problem is, that ToEnum fails to compile because the relevant StringToEnum functions haven't been defined before it is.

Is there a useful way this can be coded, or am I stuck with needing to write two lines of code whenever I want to declare and initialize an enum value from a string?

I tried to specialize ToEnum, but that suffers from the problem that I need to close the namespace I'm defining the enum in, open the CommonCode namespace and add to that, then go back to original namespace again. This is a lot of typing and looks pretty ugly.

(I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, so any solutions that compile with that would be preferred).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you can't make `StringToEnum` just return a `Color` rather than passing in a reference.

Comment: @TartanLlama because it would be possible only for `Color`. Wouldn't be possible to use for other enums

Comment: Unclear why a) `StringToEnum` can't return color itself. b) why it can't be declared before `ToEnum` template.

Comment: What about `Color c = StringToEnum(L"red", c);` where you ignore the passed reference of `c` but use it only for its type?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, how do you mean? As a matter of fact, it's **WAY** better to return by value rather than by reference.

Comment: @TartanLlama Imagine I also have enum class Animal { dog, cat }. If I define StringToEnum twice, once for Animal and once for Color I get an error saying there's a duplicate definition. You can't overload on return type. But, I thought there might be some template magic that lets me specify the return type.

Comment: I will return c as return value, but use an extra arg to ensure there's no ambiguity when several enum types are used.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre. Yes, potentially I could auto c = StringToEnum(L"red", Color());   So I don't need to declare c in advance.

Comment: Ah, yes, MSVC's mis-implementation of two phase lookup strikes again.

Comment: @Barry does it? Is this really just a bug, or would I have this problem with all compilers?

Comment: @ScottLangham "The problem is, that ToEnum fails to compile because the relevant StringToEnum functions haven't been defined before it is." <== would work just fine if dependent name lookup was correct.

Comment: Why not use static maps instead of functions for `ToString` and `StringToEnum` ?

Comment: @ScottLangham: and make 2nd argument an unnamed constant reference. But you would have to make sure noone passes `c` as second argument and ignores return value or that will introduce a bug (no warning issued)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StringToEnum` should actually return an `Enum`. As-is, it's somewhat obnoxious to use at best. Since MSVC [incorrectly implements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6273176/2069064) two-phase template lookup, your function template solution fails. So instead, let's just pass in something else into `StringToEnum` that we can use to determine the type. To make it as clear as possible what the purpose of this "something else" is, we'll make it its own type:

```
template <class T> struct tag { };
```

In your original example:

```
inline Color StringToEnum(const std::wstring& inEnumValueName, tag<Color> )
{
    if (inEnumValueName == L"red")
    {
        return Color::red;
    }
    else if (inEnumValueName == L"green")
    {
        return Color::green;
    }
    // etc.
}
```

So now whenever you want to convert a string to enum `E`, that's just:

```
auto e = StringToEnum(str, tag<E>{});
```

Which could be shortened with a generic overload:

```
template <class T>
inline T StringToEnum(const std::wstring& name) {
    return StringToEnum(name, tag<T>{} );
}

auto e = StringToEnum<E>(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You have different namespaces. You template declaration is almost correct, but it needs yo know what is `StringToEnum`. You simply need to put the namespace when you use the function:</strike>

```
namespace CommonCode {
    template<class T>
    T ToEnum(const std::wstring& enumValueName) {
        T value;

        // Notice the namespace here
        Mine::StringToEnum(enumValueName, value);
        return value;
    }
}
```

What I would recommend is to directly instantiate every function directly:

```
template<class T>
T toEnum(const std::string&);

template<>
Color toEnum<Color>(const std::string&) {
    if (inEnumValueName == L"red") {
        out = Color::red;
    }

    // ...
}
```

It will remove boilerplate and let you use your function like you wanted, and is implemented in the right way for that syntax.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure this is right. I think C++ will find the function even if it's in another namespace because of argument dependant lookup as described here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl

Answer (score 0):

You can use template specialization:

```
#include <string>

enum class Fail { err };
enum class Color { red,blue,green};

//generic template: causes error in compilation
template<typename T> 
T enumToString(std::string s)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(T) == -1,"no overload for enum");
}

//specialization for Color
template<>
Color enumToString(std::string s)
{
    if(s == "red") 
        return Color::red;
    else if(s == "blue")
        return Color::blue;
    return Color::green;
}

int main()
{

    auto c = enumToString<Color>("blue");
//  auto e = enumToString<Fail>("e"); //this will cause a compiler error
    return static_cast<int>(c);
}
```

Just specialize the template for each enum you need. I also added a default implementation, which will fail if no specialization is there.