# Bizarre template errors when compiling in Visual C++ with /permissive-

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates

I'm trying to compile some code in VS2019 with /permissive- that involves both templates and overloading and wierd things are happening.
(https://godbolt.org/z/fBbQu6)

As in the godbolt, when my templateFunc() is declared between two overloads like so:

```cpp
namespace Foospace {
    class A;
    void func(A*) {};

    template<class T> void templateFunc() { Foospace::func((T*)0); }

    class B;
    void func(B*) {};

    void func() { Foospace::templateFunc<B>(); }
}
```

I get `error C2664: 'void Foospace::func(Foospace::A *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'T *' to 'Foospace::A *'`

If I move the templateFunc() below the overloads, it obviously works:

```cpp
namespace Foospace {
    class A;
    void func(A*) {};

    class B;
    void func(B*) {};

    template<class T> void templateFunc() { Foospace::func((T*)0); }

    void func() { Foospace::templateFunc<B>(); }
}
```

And if I move templateFunc() before both overloads that also works:

```cpp
namespace Foospace {
    template<class T> void templateFunc() { Foospace::func((T*)0); }

    class A;
    void func(A*) {};

    class B;
    void func(B*) {};

    void func() { Foospace::templateFunc<B>(); }
}
```

And if I keep templateFunc() between the two overloads but simply remove the `Foospace` namespace qualifier from the call to func() then suddenly that also works too:

```cpp
namespace Foospace {
    class A;
    void func(A*) {};

    template<class T> void templateFunc() { func((T*)0); }

    class B;
    void func(B*) {};

    void func() { Foospace::templateFunc<B>(); }
}
```

What is going on here?

Comment: This looks like a compiler bug. The third case should fail. The rules are arcane, but you can start by looking up ADL and two phase lookup.

Answer (score 6):

There are a lot of C++ rules at play here.

- [Qualified name lookup](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.lookup.qual)
- [Unqualified name lookup](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.lookup.unqual)
- [Argument-dependent lookup](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.lookup.argdep)
- [Dependent name lookup](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.dep) and [template name resolution](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.res) (a.k.a. [two-phase lookup](http://blog.llvm.org/2009/12/dreaded-two-phase-name-lookup.html))

As Herb Sutter [put it](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/087.htm), "*difficulty 9/10*".

Let's consider the cases one by one.

```
namespace Foospace {
    class A;
    void func(A*) {};

    template<class T> void templateFunc() { Foospace::func((T*)0); }

    class B;
    void func(B*) {};

    void func() { Foospace::templateFunc<B>(); }
}
```

Here we have *qualified lookup* inside a template. The name `Foospace::func` is looked up and "bound" [at the point of template definition](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.res#temp.dep.candidate-1.1). Only `func(A*)` is known at that time and thus the subsequent call to `func(B*)` fails. The compiler is right to reject the code. Note that this [wasn't implemented](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/two-phase-name-lookup-support-comes-to-msvc/) in MSVC until recently.

```
namespace Foospace {
    class A;
    void func(A*) {};

    class B;
    void func(B*) {};

    template<class T> void templateFunc() { Foospace::func((T*)0); }

    void func() { Foospace::templateFunc<B>(); }
}
```

Same story, only the lookup results in the *overload set* `func(A*)`, `func(B*)`. So both calls succeed.

```
namespace Foospace {
    template<class T> void templateFunc() { Foospace::func((T*)0); }

    class A;
    void func(A*) {};

    class B;
    void func(B*) {};

    void func() { Foospace::templateFunc<B>(); }
}
```

Here the lookup finds nothing. The code should fail to compile. For some reason MSVC compiles it, which suggests it's either a bug or a feature/extension. GCC and clang [reject it](https://godbolt.org/z/c4_oMR).

```
namespace Foospace {
    class A;
    void func(A*) {};

    template<class T> void templateFunc() { func((T*)0); }

    class B;
    void func(B*) {};

    void func() { Foospace::templateFunc<B>(); }
}
```

Unqualified lookup here. ADL rules apply, so at template definition time it's impossible to say if `func(T*)` resolves or not so phase-1 lookup always lets it proceed. The name is looked up [at the point of template instantiation](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.res#temp.dep.candidate-1.2), when both declarations are known. The code compiles fine.

Comment: MSVC now correctly refuses the third example in 19.24 with "error C2039: 'func': is not a member of 'Foospace'"

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with MSVC and two-phase lookup.

In Visual Studio 2017 version 15.3 and later, by default, the compiler uses two-phase name lookup for template name resolution.

The **`/permissive-`** option implicitly sets the **conforming** two-phase lookup compiler behavior, but it can be overridden by using **`/Zc:twoPhase-`**.

If the option **`/Zc:twoPhase-`** is specified, the compiler reverts to its previous **non-conforming** class template and function template name resolution and substitution behavior.

With this option set, the code compiles. See **[godbolt demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/xSKXqM)**

Related bug reports:

1. [Implement correct two-phase lookup for C++ templates](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/351076/implement-correct-two-phase-lookup-for-c-templates.html)
2. [Using /permissive- in a C++/CLI project triggers two-phase name lookup warnings](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/70133/using-permissive-in-a-ccli-project-triggers-two-ph.html)

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273176/what-exactly-is-broken-with-microsoft-visual-cs-two-phase-template-instanti) and its answers which details some issues with MSVC in this regard.

Comment: P.W: Both of those bug reports are closed as fixed. They claim that 2 phase lookup is implemented correctly now.
The other post appears to be talking about MSVC's behavior from before it supported 2 phase lookup.

Comment: @AngusGraham:  If their claim is correct, should we not seeing the same compiler behavior with and without the `/Zc:twoPhase-` option?