# Does the order of the template funcation declaration matter in g++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++

When I write a merge sort with recursion, I declared the `mergeSort(T arr[], int n)` and inner one `mergeSort(T arr[], int p, int r)` with a `merge(T arr[], int p, int q, int r)` function in this order. And when I compile it the MSVC works OK, but g++ gives me output like this:

```sh
In file included from sortalgtest.cpp:1:0:
./sortalg.h: In instantiation of ‘void mergeSort(T*, int) [with T = int]’:
sortalgtest.cpp:8:61:   required from here
./sortalg.h:193:14: error: no matching function for call to ‘mergeSort(int*&, int, int)’
     mergeSort(arr, 0, n - 1);
     ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./sortalg.h:191:6: note: candidate: template<class T> void mergeSort(T*, int)
 void mergeSort(T arr[], int n)
      ^~~~~~~~~
./sortalg.h:191:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
./sortalg.h:193:14: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided
     mergeSort(arr, 0, n - 1);
     ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I guess the cause might be the order of functions' declaration and I changed declaration order by calling. And this time g++ works too. What I want to know is why this works?

```cpp
template <typename T>
void mergeSort(T arr[], int n)
{
    mergeSort(arr, 0, n - 1);
}

template <typename T>
void mergeSort(T arr[], int p, int r)
{
    if (p >= r)
        return;

    int q = p + (r - p) / 2;
    mergeSort(arr, p, q);
    mergeSort(arr, q + 1, r);

    merge(arr, p, q, r);
}

template <typename T>
void merge(T arr[], int p, int q, int r)
{
    // merge ...
}
```

Does this caused by a compiler specific feature?

Comment: GCC is right.  MSVC is known to have trouble implementing two-phase name lookup.

Comment: In simple cases like this, the standard rule is just the same as with non-template functions, which must be declared before use.

Comment: Old versions of MSVC are bugged , [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47357657/1505939)

Comment: Thanks for your answers! But in my case(declaration order shown as above) MSVC can do the compile and worked as expected while g++ gave me some error messages. I use vs 2015 and simple `cl xxx.cpp`. The version of gcc is 7.4.0 and the command I use is `g++ xxx.cpp -o xxx.out`.  Could you please give me some more information?