# C++: syntax error detected by MSVC only using Boost::asio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost-asio

I'm making a basic client-server architecture in C++ using Boost::ASIO.

MSVC reports a `syntax error: '.'` **(C2059)** at this line:

```cpp
void
Server::start()
{
  m_stopped = false;
  listen_one();

  m_runner = std::make_unique<std::thread>([this](){
    io_service.run(); // <- syntax error: '.'
  });

  m_runner->detach();
}
```

- GCC and Clang both compile the same code on Linux and macOS just fine.
- The code has been changed several times and compiled several imes, and the error persists.
- There is this other block of code, which MSVC does **not** detect as an error:

```cpp
void
Client::init()
{
  m_socket->connect(boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(
                              boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(m_ip),
                              static_cast<short unsigned int>(m_port)));
  
  Connection::init();

  m_runner = std::make_unique<std::thread>([this](){
    io_service.run(); // <- this line is fine
  });

  m_runner->detach();
}
```

Basic debugging:

- `io_service`, `m_stopped`, `m_runner` are member variables of Server, and `listen_one()` is a member function.
- Server does not inherit anything. (If relevant, Client inherits another class, Connection)

---

Why does MSVC detect a syntax error, but neither GCC nor Clang do?

Comment: Can you try `this->io_service.run()`? MSVC has been challenged with two-phase lookup for a very long time. Perhaps that's it

Comment: @sehe Well, somehow, it solved the problem. Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you try this->io_service.run()?

MSVC has been challenged with two-phase lookup for a very long time.

- [What exactly is "broken" with Microsoft Visual C++'s two-phase template instantiation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273176/what-exactly-is-broken-with-microsoft-visual-cs-two-phase-template-instanti)
- http://blog.llvm.org/2009/12/dreaded-two-phase-name-lookup.html
- [Two-phase name lookup support comes to MSVC](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/two-phase-name-lookup-support-comes-to-msvc/) (2017)

Perhaps that's it. What `this->` makes explicit is that `io_service` represents a class member. In the lambda shown it shouldn't usually matter (except perhaps if the class is actually declared [as part of] a template?).

Another factor at play could be name shadowing: `io_service` shadows the name of the type. If that type name is visible without namespace qualification, then it might cause confusion to MSVC.