# Rules of injecting behavior to templated function using function overloading

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation

When writing templated libraries, sometimes it is desirable to implement behavior later than the definition of a function template. For example, I'm thinking of a `log` function in a logger library that is implemented as

```cpp
template< typename T >
void log(const T& t) {
    std::cout << "[log] " << t << std::endl;
}
```

Later if I want to use `log` on my own type, I would implement `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, CustomType)` and hope that `log` function works on `CustomType` automatically.

However, I'm very unsure whether this pattern is conformant to the standard. To see how compilers treat it, I wrote the following minimal example.

```cpp
#include<iostream>

// In some library...
void foo(double)         { std::cout << "double" << std::endl; }
template< typename T>
void doFoo(T x) {
    foo(x);
}

// In some codes using the library...
struct MyClass {};
template< typename T > struct MyClassT {};
namespace my { struct Class {}; }

void foo(MyClass)        { std::cout << "MyClass" << std::endl; }
void foo(MyClassT<int>)  { std::cout << "MyClassT<int>" << std::endl; }
void foo(my::Class)      { std::cout << "my::Class" << std::endl; }
void foo(int)            { std::cout << "int" << std::endl; }


int main() {

    doFoo(1.0);               // okay, prints "double".
    doFoo(MyClass{});         // okay, prints "MyClass".
    doFoo(MyClassT<int>{});   // okay, prints "MyClassT<int>".
    doFoo(42);                // not okay, prints "double". int seems to have been converted to double.
    // doFoo(my::Class{});    // compile error, cannot convert my::Class to int.

    return 0;
}
```

where I hope to inject to `doFoo` function template by overloading the `foo` function. The results seem very inconsistent, because it works for custom (templated) types, but not for custom types in namespaces or built-in types. The results are the same for compilers MSVC (bundled with Visual Studio 16.10.1), as well as gcc 9.3.0.

I'm now very confused about what should be the correct behavior. I guess it has something to do with the location of instantiation. My questions are:

1. Are the codes above legal? Or are they ill-formed?
2. If the codes are legal, what causes the inconsistent behaviors for different overloads?
3. If the codes are illegal, what would be a good alternative to injecting library templates? (I'm thinking of passing functions/functors explicitly to my `doFoo` function, like what `<algorithm>` is doing.)

Comment: I can’t seem to find a proper duplicate, but this is dependent ADL, which is surely well discussed somewhere.

Comment: If trying to figure out the behavior, I recommend not using Visual C++ for that purpose, since for backward compatibility with legacy code a lot of Visual C++ versions processed templates with single-phase lookup instead of the two-phase lookup required by the C++ standard.  It didn't even try to support the correct behavior [until 2017 and even then it defaulted to the old behavior](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/two-phase-name-lookup-support-comes-to-msvc/)

Comment: Required reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6273465/103167

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the codes are illegal, what would be a good alternative to injecting library templates? (I'm thinking of passing functions/functors explicitly to my `doFoo` function, like what `<algorithm>` is doing.)

You can combine functors with a default trait type to get a "best of both worlds". That's essentially how the unordered containers in the standard library use `std::hash`.

It allows injection either via specializing the trait or passing a functor explicitly.

```cpp
#include<iostream>

// In some library...
template <typename T>
struct lib_trait;

template<>
struct lib_trait<double> {
    void operator()(double) const         { std::cout << "double" << std::endl; }
};

template<typename T, typename CbT=lib_trait<T>>
void doFoo(T x, const CbT& cb={}) {
    cb(x);
}

// In some codes using the library...
struct MyClass {};
template< typename T > struct MyClassT {};
namespace my { struct Class {}; }

template<>
struct lib_trait<MyClass> {
    void operator()(MyClass) const        { std::cout << "MyClass" << std::endl; }
};

template<>
struct lib_trait<MyClassT<int>> {
    void operator()(MyClassT<int>) const  { std::cout << "MyClassT<int>" << std::endl; }
};

template<>
struct lib_trait<int> {
    void operator()(int) const            { std::cout << "int" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {

    // Leverage default argument to get the same syntax.
    doFoo(1.0);               // okay, prints "double".

    // Handled by specializations defined later.
    doFoo(MyClass{});         // okay, prints "MyClass".
    doFoo(MyClassT<int>{});   // okay, prints "MyClassT<int>".
    doFoo(42);                // okay, prints "int".

    // Pass in an explicit functor.
    doFoo(my::Class{}, [](const auto&){});

    return 0;
}
```