# What is the rationale for == having higher precedence than bitwise AND, XOR, and OR?

Tags: c++, c, bitwise-operators, operator-precedence, comparison-operators

In C++, what is the rationale for == and != having higher precedence than bitwise AND, XOR, and OR?

It would seem to me more natural to have `operator==` and `operator!=` come after `operator&`, `operator^`, and `operator|`.  I'd like to understand the motivation so that I can better remember the ordering.

For example, I would think the following kind of usage would be common:

```
if (bitFields & value == 0) { // Incorrect test.
  // Do Something.
}
```

Since the == result is either 1 or 0, why would you ever want to use it for bitwise operations?  Instead, the above must be written as:

```
if ((bitFields & value) == 0) { // Correct test.
  // Do Something.
}
```

to get the intended meaning where the bitwise AND is done before the comparison to zero.

Comment: The rationale for C++ is, that C uses the same precedence rules. You should change the question to C.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C Operator precedence (bitwise & lower than ==)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685072/c-operator-precedence-bitwise-lower-than)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. It is historical from C
2. Consider using functions in your `if` statement

e.g.

```
if (func1() == 2 & func2() == 3)
```

With the precedence of `==` being higher that `&` ensures that both functions are called.

Comment: That does not seem to be proper use of a bitwise AND.

Comment: @Matt, It's a perfectly justified use: no short-circuiting.

Comment: What if `func1()` returns 1 and `func2()` returns 2?

Comment: @mkb Then 1 == 2 => 0. 2 == 3 => 0. 0 & 0 => 0.

Comment: My mind blocked out the `==` operators some how. Need more coffee.

Comment: @chris Even so, that doesn't seem to be enough justification for the precedence rules. `if ((func1() == 2) & (func2() == 3))` is not that difficult to write on the rare occasion that you need to. Comparing bitwise operations, however, is not so rare.

Comment: @Matt, True, I agree with that.

Comment: @Ed: Part of your answer is misleading. Precedence has nothing to do with whether both functions are called. Even if it were switched, both would still be called; the result of the expression is the only thing that would change.

Comment: @Matt: it's historical from before `&&` and `||` were introduced to the language.  Originally, `&` and `|` were all that was available, so this behavior made more sense.

Comment: @StephenCanon `&&` and `||` existed when K&R was first published. Does anything before K&R really even count?

Comment: @Matt: Yes; see the "Neonatal C" section of http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html

Comment: @R - Consider if the precedence was switched, end up computing `2 & func2()` first to get a value (say `x`). Now the expression becomes `func1() == x == 3`!

Comment: @StephenCanon Thanks, that was an interesting article!