# Intuitive reasons why >= is higher precedence than |

Tags: c++, c

What are intuitive reasons for `>=` and '>' to be higher precedence than `|`? [Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).
I could understand why `||` is lower as writing `a>b||c` is common. However I'd think `a>b|c` would be doing an OR before the compare. This doesn't seem intuitive. What are examples of `&^|` being lower precedence then compare/equity operators being intuitive?

Comment: See this SO question/answer: [C operator precedence bitwiser lower than equality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685072/c-operator-precedence-bitwise-lower-than).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a historical accident, in [The Development of the C Language](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/chist.html), Dennis Ritchie wrote:

> Their tardy introduction explains an infelicity of C's precedence rules. In B one writes

```
    if (a==b & c) ...
```

> to check whether a equals b and c is non-zero; in such a conditional expression it is better that & have lower precedence than ==. In converting from B to C, one wants to replace & by && in such a statement; to make the conversion less painful, we decided to keep the precedence of the & operator the same relative to ==, and merely split the precedence of && slightly from &. Today, it seems that it would have been preferable to move the relative precedences of & and ==, and thereby simplify a common C idiom: to test a masked value against another value, one must write

```
    if ((a&mask) == b) ...
```

> where the inner parentheses are required but easily forgotten.

So it's because B used `|` and `&` for the logical operators, and C kept the precedence for the thus-denoted bitwise operators.

Comment: "Historical accident" seems a strange term to use for something that clearly wasn't an accident at all. Historical *artifact*, maybe.

Comment: @RobKennedy I had the impression that decisions that later turned out to be suboptimal were often tongue-in-cheek called "historical accident". I have seen the phrase used that way a couple of times before, or at least I interpreted it such.

Comment: Thanks for the link to that article.  Very interesting read!