# Bit operations for returning the next-highest power of 2

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I want to create a function that returns the next multiple of 2^p.

Here's an attempt, but not sure if it works...:

```
#define P 20
#define ALIGN_FORWARD(x, alignment) ((((int)x) + ((alignment)-1)) & (~((alignment)-1)))

int round_up(int x) 
{
  return ALIGN_FORWARD(x, P);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you run it and test it and see whether it works?

Comment: `(1<<p)`, key element of anything that deals with `2^p`, is missing from your formula, so I am pretty sure it's not right. See [this page](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html), it may have what you need.

Comment: code it as straight code, test it and then (only just then) covert it to a macro

Comment: @dasblinkenlight No, this is not an exponentiation function but a rounding function. However, it can't be done without count-leading-zeroes (or some repetition), and you do need such an exponentiation function to get from leading-zeroes to the result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write a C function that round up a number to next power of 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813008/write-a-c-function-that-round-up-a-number-to-next-power-of-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet first fills up all bits below the highest set bit. After `v |= v >> 1` the first two bits can be copied and so on. Finally the value is incremented by one.

```
uint32_t v = ...;
v |= v >> 1;
v |= v >> 2;
v |= v >> 4;
v |= v >> 8;
v |= v >> 16;
v += 1;
```

The `unsigned` part of `uint32_t` is important, because otherwise the result would be always `0`, because the sign bit gets extended by the shift operation. If the value is a `uint64_t`, then you have to add a further shift, if it is a `uint16_t`, then you have to remove a shift.

For an input of 8 the result would be 16. You need to test if the input is a power of two if you don't like that. Knowing that the binary representation of a power of two is one character shorter when you decrement it (8=0b1000, 7=0b111), you can use this guard:

```
if ((v & (v - 1)) > 0) {
    …
}
```

(Reproduced from memory. Original from https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#RoundUpPowerOf2, which contains many more interesting tricks.)