# python XOR for two integers

Tags: python, xor

Coming from a Java background into Python and working my way through CodingBat (*Python* > *Warmup-1* > *pos_neg*) the following confused me greatly:

```
    >>> True ^ False 
    True 
    >>> 1<0 ^ -1<0 
    False
```

I appreciate the following:

```
    >>> (1<0) ^ (-1<0)
    True
```

But what is python interpreting `1<0 ^ -1<0` as to return false?

Comment: Because it evaluates `1<0 ^ -1<0` as `1<(0 ^ -1)<0`, which is `1 < -1 < 0`, which is `(1 < -1) and (-1 < 0)`, which is obviously `False`. Learn your operator precedence!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^` has [higher precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html) than `<`.

Thus, what is being evaluated is actually `1 < -1 < 0`, where `0 ^ -1 = -1`

And thus you rightly get `False`, since the inequality clearly does not hold.

You almost never have to remember the precedence table. Just neatly use parenthesis.

You might want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813008/write-a-c-function-that-round-up-a-number-to-next-power-of-2/14813121#14813121) out as well, which discusses an identical situation.

Answer (score 1):

`0 ^ -1` equals `-1`. `1 < -1 < 0` is `False` since 1 is greater than -1. Python chains relational operators naturally, hence `1 < -1 < 0` is equivalent to `(1 < -1) and (-1 < 0)`.