# (const char*)++ or (const char)++?

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char *str = "hello";

    while (*str) {
        cout << *str;
        *str++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char *str = "hello";

    while (*str) {
        cout << *str;
        str++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

both output

```
hello
```

Why doesn't adding or removing the deference operator before `str++` alter the output?

Comment: Dont use char*, use std::string instead.

Comment: Either enable those [compiler warnings](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4bed875ce521867b) (one of them should actually be an error in C++11) or pay attention to them.

Comment: Tip: When I need to remember operator precedence, I Google "c operator" and click the Wikipedia result. Also noteworthy: "a&b == 0" (with & being "bitwise and") means "a & (b==0)"

Comment: @leewangzhong, If you don't know why that is, you might find this interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685072/c-operator-precedence-bitwise-lower-than

Comment: Yep, I saw it before, and did find it interesting. I found out about it for PHP first and thought PHP was being silly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*str++` means `*(str++)`.

Since you don't use the value of that expression, the `*` has no effect.

Comment: I see. It's basically the same as `str++; *str;` and the latter statement doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 6):

Postfix `++` has higher precedence than the de-rerference operator `*`, so

```
*x++;
```

is the same as

```
*(x++);
```

which really does the same as

```
x++;
```

Comment: Your first version was actually correct. Prefix-`++` and `*` have the same precedence, postfix-`++` has higher precedence.