# GCC: suggest parentheses around comparison parentheses not able to solve myself

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, parentheses

I am trying to check whether this equal to zero as

```
//Address already malloc

void MyCheck (void *Address){

    if ( (long)Address & (~(sizeof(long)-1)) != 0 ){
           printf("Invalid");
    }

}
```

When try to compile it give me:

```
Error:  suggest parentheses around comparison in operand 
         of '&' [-Werror=parentheses]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`!=` has higher precedence than `&` , so your code is really doing the same as :

```
if ((long)Address &  ( (~(sizeof(long)-1)) != 0 ) )
                     ^                          ^
```

gcc suggests this might be an error, which it probably is. You'd want:

```
if ( ( (long)Address &  (~(sizeof(long)-1)) ) != 0 )
     ^                                      ^
```

Comment: @haccks Um. that chart has `!=` *above* `&` , unless you're suggesting the chart is in low-to-high order, which it isn't.

Comment: @haccks C operators in order of precedence (highest to lowest).

Comment: @WhozCraig; My bad. I looked over here `=
+=  -=
*=  /=
%=  &=
^=  |=
<<=  >>=` and thought `|=` to be `!=` :)

Comment: In case anyone cares : [Near-Duplicate Question Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685072/c-operator-precedence-bitwise-lower-than)

Answer (score 2):

Place a braces around `(long)Address & (~(sizeof(long)-1))` in `if` statement.

```
if ( ( (long)Address & (~(sizeof(long)-1)) ) != 0 ){
```

Comment: Then it is always untrue/Invalid

Comment: Then what do you want to do?

Answer (score 2):

`!=` is of a higher level of precedence than `&`, so what you're actually saying is:

```
if ((long)Address & ((~(sizeof(long)-1)) != 0)){
       printf("Invalid");
}
```

Instead, put parentheses around the first part:

```
if (((long)Address & (~(sizeof(long)-1))) != 0){
       printf("Invalid");
}
```

However, having a lot of background in TI-Basic and C, I would personally leave out the `!= 0` part:

```
if ((long)Address & (~(sizeof(long)-1))){
       printf("Invalid");
}
```

Comment: Your answer is also correct but for validation i need !=0

Comment: @Vineet1982 Just in case someday 0 != 0, you want to be absolutely sure ? The last snippet in this is defined to do exactly what the second does. If by validate you mean appeasing some code reviewer that doesn't know C from A, B, or ice-cream, ugh, but ok.

Answer (score 1):

Although other answers have addressed the compiler error, you could sidestep the problem with:

```
if ((uintptr_t) Address % sizeof(long)) …
```

(To get `uintptr_t`, include `<stdint.h>`. And, if you are using C 2011, you might want to replace `sizeof(long)` with `_Alignof(long)`.)

Comment: That's probably what he meant to do, but with the `~`, is that really what it does?

Comment: @MarcGlisse: Good point, but who can tell with all the parentheses and absence of documentation?