# C: Why Bitwise AND works for special character

Tags: c

I'm trying to write simple program using c to compute the intersection between two strings using `Bitwise AND` operator Like :

```
        char x[]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        char y[]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

        int i,sum=0;
        const int size = 26;

        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        {   
            if(x[i]&y[i]==y[i]){
                printf("%c",y[i]);
                sum++;
            }
        }

        printf("\n%d\n",sum);
```

After executing code i found the result :

```
acegikmoqsuw
13
```

what's the problem with my code or what's the reason for that ?

Comment: "what's the problem with my code" - you're using bitwise and. Don't know why, or what you expect it to do... clarify.

Comment: You are seeing only odd ASCII characters. Quite literally.

Comment: The title of your question does not match the actual question.

Comment: mmmmmmm thanks i will do my best next time :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take care of operand precedence in the `if`:

```
    char x[]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    char y[]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    int i,sum=0;
    const int size = 26;

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if((x[i] & y[i]) == y[i])
        {
            printf("%c",y[i]);
            sum++;
        }
    }

    printf("\n%d\n",sum);
```

Comment: It might be an example of a more complicated thing, like, for example, where `x != y`.

Comment: yes you are write thanks but why i should write like that i always write this expression with no error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685072/operator-precedence-bitwise-lower-than
The && and || operators were added later for their "short-circuiting" behavior. Dennis Ritchie admits in retrospect that the precedence of the bitwise operators should have been changed when the logical operators were added. But with several hundred kilobytes of C source code in existence at that point and an installed base of three computers, Dennis thought it would be too big of a change in the C language...

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't strictly correct; if every `x[i]` were `0xff` then it'd think that every character matched. All you're going to detect is anywhere that the relevant `x` has a `0` that the relevant `y` does not.

If the requirement is to use `&`, for whatever academic purpose, then run the test in both directions:

```
if( (x[i]&y[i])==y[i] && (x[i]&y[i])==x[i] )
```

i.e. if there are no bits set in `y` that are not also set in `x` *and* there are no bits set in `x` that are not also set in `y` then the two must have the same bit pattern.

Though, obviously:

```
if( x[i]==y[i] )
```

... is the intended means of testing for equality in C.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in the evaluation of the if statement

```
if(x[i]&y[i]==y[i])
```

the == operator has greater precedence than the & operator. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence

Try replacing it with this:

```
if( (x[i] & y[1]) == y[1] )
```