# What does "&varname == varname" mean?

Tags: c++

I've inherited a C++ project at work, it's an application originally written for Windows XP that presents visual stimuli during psych experiments. I can't figure out this line here that checks for syntax errors in the control file:

```
else if((m_SectorSwitchData.SectorType &ET_TMS == ET_TMS) & (m_SectorSwitchData.SectorType | ET_TMS != ET_TMS))
```

I can't find any documentation on what the "&ET_TMS == ET_TMS" means, is it a typo? [The Wikipedia page on C++ operators doesn't mention it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) and Visual Studio doesn't mark it wrong.

Comment: The lesson here is: Consistent spacing (and spacing to begin with) makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the bitwise and operation.  To make it easier to parse you could add a space and some parentheses to make it easier to read:

```
(m_SectorSwitchData.SectorType & ET_TMS) == ET_TMS
```

---

Do note that this change will actually change the behavior of the code.  `&` has a lower precedence than `==` so

```
(m_SectorSwitchData.SectorType & ET_TMS == ET_TMS)
```

is actually

```
(m_SectorSwitchData.SectorType & (ET_TMS == ET_TMS))
```

This is mostly a mistake by the original author and

```
((m_SectorSwitchData.SectorType & ET_TMS) == ET_TMS)
```

is most likely what they intended to have.  This also applies to the second part of the if statement.

Answer (score 5):

There *is* a typo, but it's not with the `&`.

The typo is that `a & b == c` means `a & (b == c)` when, at least to me, it looks like the author probably intended `(a & b) == c`.

Now, don't be misled by the missing space — this is not a reference or an address-of operation or anything like that; it's a bitwise AND with the subsequent conventional whitespace omitted. In the mirror-image condition immediately after it you see a similar condition, except with bitwise OR and the whitespace included.

C++ doesn't really care about whitespace as long as tokens can be identified unambiguously, and it can identify them unambiguously based on what is valid where.

```
a &b
a & b
a& b
a&b
```

Given that `a` and `b` are already known to be expressions, the above four lines are equivalent.

Of course, if `a` were a typename, then they would all be declarations (or parts of a declaration) of a reference called `b`!

Those with sense, though, write the expression variety like this:

```
a & b
```

…and the declaration variety like this:

```
a& b
```

Some people with no sense write the declaration variety like this:

```
a &b
```

… but nobody I know would write the expression variety like that, because it's weird and confusing, as you've discovered. :)

Comment: The code is rather obscure to me and I refrained from guessing because it is `a & b == b` where even `(a & b) == b` doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @Pixelchemist It's a common idiom for seeing whether bitmask `b` matches `a`.

Comment: @Pixelchemist `if(a & 3)`: *any* of least two significant bits set; `if((a & 3) == 3)`: *both* of set!

Answer (score 2):

In fact, equality comparison `==` has higher precedence than bitwise and `&`.

`a & b == b` is the same as `a & (b == b)` but not `(a & b) == b`.

Comment: @Caleth If that's confusing, that's because it kind of is, though [there may be _some_ logic to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4685115/560648)

Comment: I consider bitwise & and | having lower precedence a design weakness of the language. Origin of is historical, though, as && and || simply have been added later, when precedence was already fixed (and not changed any more for compatibility reasons).

Comment: Hm, not *really* an answer to the question, is it? Even though the information given is priceless(!) for a beginner...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit and this is why I have a pathological disgust of unparenthesised mixed operators

Comment: @Aconcagua My link suggests some vague rationale though I'm not wholly convinced by it

Answer (score 0):

The line expression `(m_SectorSwitchData.SectorType & ET_TMS == ET_TMS)` can be parenthesized `((m_SectorSwitchData.SectorType & ET_TMS) == ET_TMS)` and it applies bitwise and to `m_SectorSwitchData.SectorType`. The result will be a number where only those bits of `m_SectorSwitchData.SectorType` will remain set to 1 that are 1 in the `ET_TMS` constant. Checking if this is equal to `ET_TMS` is equivalent to checking that all the bits that are 1 in `ET_TMS` are also set in `m_SectorSwitchData.SectorType`. The other half of the `if` is the opposite.

Comment: "the opposite" is ambiguous. It's true when *any* bits *not in* `ET_TMS` are set in `m_SectorSwitchData.SectorType`.