# Compare uint8_t with hexadecimal in C++

Tags: c++, atmega

Let's say I have `uint8_t bytes[maxBytes];`.

Now I want to compare the lower 6 bits of the first byte (`bytes[0]`) with `0x3c`.

I tried to do it like this:

```
bytes[0] & 0x3f == 0x3c
```

Unfortunately, this did not produce the expected result. (i.e. it's always false, even though when I print out `bytes[0] & 0x3f` , it is `0x3c`)

I've played around with this some more and found out that

```
bytes[0] & 0x00 == 0x00
```

is sometimes true, and sometimes false. (Same with `bytes[0] & 0x0 == 0x0` and `bytes[0] & 0x00 == 0x0`). Shouldn't it always be true?

What is going on here? How can I make my `0x3c` comparison work?

Sitenote: I'm running this code on an arduino w/ atmega328pb MCU.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operator precedence (bitwise '&' lower than '==')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685072/operator-precedence-bitwise-lower-than)

Comment: out of the missing (), if you want to compare with _0x3d_ why do you compare with _0x3c_ ?

Comment: `auto value = bytes[0] & 0x3f;` then do `if (value == 0x3d) ...`

Comment: read compiler warnings and you'll find out the root cause immediately. For example [gcc says *warning: & has lower precedence than ==; == will be evaluated first \[-Wparentheses\]*](https://godbolt.org/z/aklyuM)

Comment: @bruno that was a typo. fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need parentheses:

```
(bytes[0] & 0x3f) == 0x3c
```

This is because of the weird precedences of `&` and `|` which were inherited from C, which inherited them from B (Dennis Ritchie described this precedence problem in https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html).