# Why does my implementation of (Leetcode #231) Power of Two give the wrong result?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

The problem asks to write a function that takes an integer as input and to return true if the integer is a power of two. I want to write my function using both the bitwise AND operator and logical shifting to practice these concepts. I tried to walk through many input examples and thought my code would work fine, but when Leetcode used a test case of "n=2", my code returned false instead of true.

My train of thought is that if the least significant bit ANDed with 1 equals to 0 (I'm trying to bitmask and only perform the AND operation on the n's LSB), then there is potential for n to be a power of 2. So I shift n one bit to the right, and evaluate if n is 1 (then yes, it's a power of 2, and return true to the function). If n is not 1, and the LSB ANDed with 1 is not 0, then that means n is definitely not a power of 2 - so I break out of the while loop and return false.

Can anyone help pinpoint what went wrong?

```
bool isPowerOfTwo(int n){

    while(n>0)
    {
        if(n==1)
            return 1;

        else if(n&1 == 0)
            n = n>>1;

        else
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or you could simply use: `return n > 0 && (n & (n-1)) == 0;`

Comment: Or for `unsigned` values simply `return v && !(v & (v - 1));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your logic is correct. Unfortunately you fell into an operator precedence trap: `==` binds tighter than `&` due to ... [history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685072/operator-precedence-bitwise-lower-than). `n&1 == 0` is parsed as if `n&(1 == 0)` which naturally is always 0.

The fix is to use `(n & 1) == 0`.